# How to get result from a module only when a button of this module is clicked?

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

### Context

Here is an app with a module where you can select the column of a data frame.
The module returns the data frame with only the selected column.

### Question

How to modify this example to make the `renderDataTable` updated only when the `Go!` button is clicked inside the module?

### Code

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

## Module
return_df_UI <- function(id, df) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    selectInput(ns("column"),
                label = "Choose a column",
                choices = names(df)),
    actionButton("go",
                 label = "Go!")
  )
}

return_df_Server <- function(id, df) {
  moduleServer( id, function(input, output, session) {
      reactive(dplyr::select(df, dplyr::all_of(input$column)))
  })
}

## App
ui <- fluidPage(
  return_df_UI("rdf", mtcars),
  dataTableOutput("out")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  selection <- return_df_Server("rdf", mtcars)
  output$out <- renderDataTable({
    selection()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

### Effort

I have tried to add `req(input$go)` inside the reactive returned by the `moduleServer` but then the `renderDataTable` is never updated :

```
return_df_Server <- function(id, df) {
  moduleServer( id, function(input, output, session) {
      reactive({
        req(input$go)
        dplyr::select(df, dplyr::all_of(input$column))
        })
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First rule I learnt about shiny modules: If the UI is not working as expected, check for missing calls to `ns`.

1. You have a missing call to `ns` on the button id.
2. Bind the (re)-calculations of the reactive to the button using `bindEvent`.

Here's the updated code:

```r
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

## Module
return_df_UI <- function(id, df) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    selectInput(ns("column"),
                label = "Choose a column",
                choices = names(df)),
    actionButton(ns("go"),
                 label = "Go!")
  )
}

return_df_Server <- function(id, df) {
  moduleServer( id, function(input, output, session) {
    reactive(dplyr::select(df, dplyr::all_of(input$column))) |> bindEvent(input$go)
  })
}

## App
ui <- fluidPage(
  return_df_UI("rdf", mtcars),
  dataTableOutput("out")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  selection <- return_df_Server("rdf", mtcars)
  output$out <- renderDataTable({
    selection()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Got lucky to make this mistake here. Because I have made it once again creating a dynamic UI with `renderUI`... I bet without your help I'd never have found it.

Comment: I'm glad you found my response helpful. Credit is all yours for making the effort to learn.